# Statistical test to use for multilevel longitudinal data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, panel-data

I'm trying to figure out which statistical test to use when testing for group differences in a multilevel longitudinal experiment

The scores (y-axis) were produced by a machine learning model, the x-axis is time (unevenly distributed: 0h, 1h, 2h, 3h, 5h)

I'm not confident which stat tests to pick

- Is this the correct situation to use a repeated measures ANOVA?
- Would it be illegal for me to also run an ANOVA + a posthoc test at the different timepoints to see how early it's possible to differentiate between groups? (more as commentary/discussion than a final result)

[image]